# Uniform shadows left of and below a corner of an HTML-element using CSS

Tags: html, css, less

**Attaching single visual shadows**

Using the [less](http://lesscss.org) **CODE#1** like in this HTML-snippet, ...

```
<div class="shadowBottom"  style="width: 200px;" >
   ... stuff here ...
</div>
```

one can easily attach shadows to e.g. DIV-sections of HTML-pages:

[image: CSS shadow below lower edge]

The [less](http://lesscss.org) code adds box-shadows below the lower-left and the lower-right corner of an element and rotates them a bit. Using `z-index=-1` the shadows get behind the target element. Thus, only some shadow gets visible just below the target element. É voilà!

Certainly, the target element needs to have a **non-transparent background** to not show the box-shadowed element at **z-index=-1**.

**Attaching two visual shadows**

With quite similar code, a shadow left of the lower/left corner is possible.

To combine both shadow effects, one needs to wrap two `DIVs` around the actual content [applying both classes to the same DIV does not work]:

```
<div class="shadowLeft" style="width: 200px;">
   <div class="shadowBottom"  style="width: 200px;" >
      ... stuff here ...
   </div>
</div>
```

Renders like this:

[image: combined shadow]

Actually, this isn't what I want to achieve, since there is a **gap between the two shadow effects**.

**Question**

I'd be too happy to see how to fill the gab and generate a homogenous shadow **around the corner**. Something like this:

[image: uniform shadows around corner]

**Code#1 [[LESS]](http://lesscss.org)**

```
.shadowBottom {

    background-color: #FFFFFF;  
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;

}

@shadowRotation: 6deg;
@horizontalOffset: 0px;
@alpha: 0.2;

.shadowBottom:before {

    content: '';

    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: @horizontalOffset;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 5px rgba( 0, 0, 0, @alpha );
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 5px rgba( 0, 0, 0, @alpha );
    box-shadow: 0 10px 5px rgba( 0, 0, 0, @alpha );

    -webkit-transform: rotate( -@shadowRotation );
    -moz-transform: rotate( -@shadowRotation );
    -o-transform: rotate( -@shadowRotation );
    -ms-transform: rotate( -@shadowRotation );
    transform: rotate( -@shadowRotation );

}

.shadowBottom:after {

    content: '';

    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: @horizontalOffset;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 5px rgba( 0, 0, 0, @alpha );
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 5px rgba( 0, 0, 0, @alpha );
    box-shadow: 0 10px 5px rgba( 0, 0, 0, @alpha );

    -webkit-transform: rotate( @shadowRotation );
    -moz-transform: rotate( @shadowRotation );
    -o-transform: rotate( @shadowRotation );
    -ms-transform: rotate( @shadowRotation );
    transform: rotate( @shadowRotation );

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** the closest I've got to this is by using `skew` to make a rhomb like figure:

```
.shadowBottom{
  position:relative;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.2);    
}

.shadowBottom::before, .shadowBottom::after{ 
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 50%;
  height: 90%;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 30px rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.4);   
  transform: skewX(-10deg) rotate(-4deg); 
               /* ^ skew value should be adjusted to match box w/h */
}

.shadowBottom::after{
  transform: skewX(10deg) rotate(4deg);  
               /* ^ same here */
  left: auto;
  right: 10px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://dabblet.com/gist/5022234)